# Codenameone Browercomponent Google Sign in

Tags: java, codenameone

How do i set the cross origin policy for my browser component. I believe that is the reason https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client is not loading my google sign in button on my codenameone browsercomponent

Comment: Is this a problem with the simulator or the device? Notice you can debug the CEF `BrowserComponent` in Chrome by navigating to http://localhost:8088/

Comment: CEF doesn't work on my simulator I keep getting Failed to create CEF browser on my mac os  so it makes it harder for me to debug since I have to build to test my app

Comment: Are you using Maven or Ant? Is this an M1 Mac or an Intel Mac?

Comment: M1 mac, I am using Maven

Comment: CEF isn't supported on M1 yet. We're working on that. Try downloading an Intel JDK as a workaround. We're working on addressing this.